# HTML list item gets misaligned when has text inside

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100vh;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <ul>
      <li>test</li><li></li><li>test</li><li></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see two of the list items have misaligned because there is text inside the elements. Whenever the text is removed the alignment is perfect. I could not find anything wrong when inspecting the element.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The text is changing the baseline of the elements. Give your `li`'s a `vertical-align` of `top`, `middle` or `bottom`:

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100vh;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  vertical-align: top; /* or middle or bottom */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<ul>
<li>test</li><li></li><li>test</li><li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Floating the `<li>` left solves the issue

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  width: 400px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100vh;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  list-style-type: none;
  min-height: 100px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<ul>
<li>test</li><li></li><li>test</li><li></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Darren we can't use float:left in li because there is already display:inline-block. We should one but not both.

Answer (score 0):

You should use space in empty `<li>&nbsp</li>`. I hope it will resolve your issue.
and browser will consider it as a space. Please try and let me know if works.

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
<li>test</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
<li>test</li>
<li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

set `max-height` or `height`

example

```
li{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    list-style-type: none;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 0px;
    max-height://your wish// or height
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have to just add one line to your css in "li" keeping other
>   code(html and css) untouched. Just add "float:left" to your "li"
>   element, thats it. That way they will get aligned

Comment: Also u can do it by adding "overflow:hidden" to your li